# How to avoid restarting an Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that downloads some executable (ffmpeg) and puts it into `node_modules/.ffmpeg`. It triggers a change that forces the function to restart. How do I avoid it?

Here's a piece of the log:

```
2022-11-29T16:01:13.397 [Information] Executing 'Functions.Render' (Reason='(null)', Id=fb038d89-051c-4adb-bc32-009e4620a6df)
2022-11-29T16:01:16.013 [Information] JavaScript activity function started.
2022-11-29T16:01:40.510 [Information] Host Status: {"id": "render-durable","state": "Running","version": "3.17.0.0","versionDetails": "3.17.0 Commit hash: a2c47e3bd045f6b4eec138e144fa830368ed9426","platformVersion": "99.0.7.639","instanceId": "5e5795336a674e1791e4c4a118daee66ab744eb64085f877d49cee0c12f9c15f","computerName": "10-30-0-31","processUptime": 59974,"functionAppContentEditingState": "Unknown","extensionBundle": {"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle","version": "3.17.0"}}
2022-11-29T16:01:41.161 [Information] Watched directory change of type 'Created' detected for 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\.ffmpeg\ffmpeg-25161681083400045.exe'
2022-11-29T16:01:41.162 [Information] Host configuration has changed. Signaling shutdown
2022-11-29T16:01:42.080 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 0.8 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:43.085 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 1.9 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:44.103 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 2.8 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:45.125 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 3.8 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:46.139 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 4.9 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:47.151 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 5.8 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:48.167 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 6.8 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:49.197 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 7.9 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:50.219 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 8.9 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:51.227 [Information] Downloading  ffmpeg 9.9 Mb/121.6 Mb
2022-11-29T16:01:51.693 [Error] at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.17.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:980:15)
2022-11-29T16:01:51.762 [Information] at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.17.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:7690:26)
2022-11-29T16:01:51.762 [Information] at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.17.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:7668:8)
2022-11-29T16:01:51.763 [Information] at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.17.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:22262:15)
2022-11-29T16:01:51.763 [Information] at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.17.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:21519:42)
2022-11-29T16:01:51.763 [Information] at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.17.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:21569:8)
2022-11-29T16:01:51.763 [Information] at C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.17.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:22078:18 {
2022-11-29T16:01:51.763 [Information] code: 14,
2022-11-29T16:01:51.764 [Information] metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {}, flags: 0 },
2022-11-29T16:01:51.764 [Information] details: 'GOAWAY received'
2022-11-29T16:01:51.764 [Information] }
```

Comment: cant you download that executable as part of your build process? or download it to some other directory?

Comment: I wish I could but this is downloaded by some other npm package.

And there's no build process -- it's a NodeJS application.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can still run `npm install` in a remote build. I'm using that for a NodeJS Function which uses Playwright to download browser binaries, as an example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#remote-build